# socket file cannot be deleted

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I made Rails's application, and when I run command mysql.server start,error happens

```
Starting MySQL
.....................[...]
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file 
  (/usr/local/var/mysql/XXXnoMBP.pid).
```

I run command `mysql_config --socket`,so /tmp/mysql.sock was returned.
Next I run `sudo rm -rf /tmp/mysql.sock` and enter password,so

```
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 7 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Tapped 0 formulae (40 files, 54.2KB)
Error: File exists - /Users/myname/Library/LaunchAgents
```

was returned,3rdly I run `brew services restart mysql` so Error: File exists - /Users/myname/Library/LaunchAgents was returned.What is wrong in my code?How can I fix this?